# Angular 2 custom decorator unsubscription strategy

Tags: angular, rxjs, decorator

I have a problem with subscriptions while using a custom decorator for updating some data.

The situation is like this:
I have custom decorator `UserChange`. This decorator is a method decorator and in a few components, it is used to run the component method when the user changes.
The decorator subscribes into user-stream and whenever a user changes it invokes the method:

Example:

Decorator:

```
export function UserChange(updater: UserUpdater) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function () {
      const update = updater.userChanges().subscribe(() => {
        // @ts-ignore
        return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      });
      return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

example of use in some Component:

```
@UserChange(AppModule.userUpdater)
private loadUserData() {
    this.api.getUserData.subscribe(...);
}
```

The problem is how to unsubscribe the `userChanges.subscription()` in the decorator when the component is destroyed?

Normally the subscription would be unsubscribed in `ngOnDestroy` of a component, but in this place, I have no influence on the decorator subscription. 
The same situation is in the opposite way. I have no reference to the component `subscription` to invoke `add(update)` on this. Because the `target` is the prototype of class, not the actual component class instance.

How to solve this problem? How to unsubscribe the decorator subscription?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution:

```
export function UserChange(updater: UserUpdater) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function () {
      const update = updater.userChanges().subscribe(() => {
        // @ts-ignore
        return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
      });

      target['ngOnDestroy'] = () => update.unsubscribe();

      return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```